# How to batch specify the weights of vertex groups

Tags: vertex-weights

Some bones on my model have weights of 0，I want these bones to have a small impact on a certain point. Can I batch select these bones and assign weights?
For example, selecting all the vertex groups of these bones and assigning a weight of 0.001 to a point on the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign a single vertex to a large number of bones easily?  In most cases, the easiest way to do this is going to be to select the vertex group, click the assign button, select the next vertex group, click assign, etc.  Yes, there's some redundancy in clicking the assign button that many times.

For some hard-to-imagine situations, it might be useful to set up a geometry nodes modifier to control your weights instead.

[image]

It's hard to be sure what would be best for you, because there are few situations where this would be easier than manual, per-group assignment, but this is a template for the sort of thing you can do.  Here, I'm assigning arbitrary weights to 4 bones on a vertex marked by membership in a group named "selection".  I'm using an arbitrary string to define one of these to demonstrate that GN string operations could be used to, possibly, simplify the process for a lot of bones with well-organized names.  Bone names could also be supplied by modifier inputs (and could be outputted directly as modifier outputs, rather than via "store named attribute".)  And of course, if there's arbitrary math you want, like don't replace the value if it's already higher, or whatever, you can implement that too.

The GN modifier can be applied to write the values into the mesh.  Something similar would be possible with vertex weight mix modifiers, but I can't imagine that would ever be easier than GN or manual assignment.

Comment: Thank you for providing such useful help!!! But because I have just started working with software, I am very unfamiliar with GN. If you have time, can you teach me the process of establishing nodes above？（I don't know how to create and connect them.）Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend looking at some Youtube tutorials.  Most people get started with shader nodes, and so probably the most beginner-friendly tutorials will be related to shader nodes.